# Convertir una fraccion a decimal

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos

Hola tengo un problema tengo un dato en la base de datos guardado como 1000 quisiera que al ser impreso convierta 1.000 y usar un convertidor de decimales cada vez que se use miles al ser visualizado.
Es tipo:
varchar(191)

soy principiante en laravel y bueno no tengo muchos conocimientos

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder convertir un número entero y ponerle decimales PHP tiene una función nativa que es [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). Ejemplo de uso:

```
$new_val = number_format(1000, 0, ',', '.'); // 1.000
```

En caso de que el valor 1000 lo tengas guardado como un string, tan solo tendrás que utilizar otra función nativa de PHP que es [floatval](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.floatval.php) para convertirlo a tipo float *número con decimales*. Ejemplo de uso:

```
$new_val = number_format(floatval(1000), 0, ',', '.'); // 1.000
```